# Yii disambiguate columns with three level "with" in relational query

Tags: php, activerecord, orm, yii, relational-database

In the following case:

```
'with'=>array('pros.comments', 'cons.comments')
```

the solution of disambiguating 'comments' is:

```
'with'=>array('pros.comments', 'cons.comments'=>array('alias'=>'con_comments'))
```

But what if I have three levels:

```
'with'=>array('pros.comments.author', 'cons.comments.author')
```

??? How to disambiguate both comments and author?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
'with'=array('pros.comments'=>array('alias'=>'pros_comments','with'=>array('author'=>array('alias'=>'pros_comments_author'))),'cons.comments'=>array('alias'=>'cons_comments','with'=>array('author'=>array('alias'=>'cons_comments_author'))))
```